# Firebase does not create new user

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am a newbie in Firebase. Recently I am trying to save users into Firebase but I can't. When I generate the APK and run it onto the real device(Not Emulator), the new user does not add it into the Firebase. Also, no errors shown up. Task executed properly and go to OTPActivity. Here is my complete code:

public void saveUser()
{

```
    firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(emailAddress.getText().toString(),password.getText().toString()).addOnCompleteListener(ChatUserSignUpActivity.this,new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful())
            {
                FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                Intent intent = new Intent(ChatUserSignUpActivity.this, OTPActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("phoneNum",emailAddress.getText().toString());
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(ChatUserSignUpActivity.this, task.getException().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would start by adding a failure listener, with addOnFailureListener. This could tell you if, for whatever the reason, the task is failing and you can log the reason. Could you please update the code, try it out and tell us if the failure listener gives anything?

Comment: @GregorioPalamà Let me update the code and let you know.

Comment: Is your `onComplete` even triggered?

Comment: @AlexMamo onComplete method triggered and go to another activity properly.

Comment: the strange thing is that the onComplete is triggered but you're not seeing the user in Firebase's dashboard. Could you please try to debug the app, and see what's in the task's AuthResult?

Comment: @GregorioPalamà One more thing I am run the app on my android device, not on the emulator. Is it a problem???

Comment: Nope, it is fine. Can you debug the application via your device?

Comment: @GregorioPalamà I am trying to print the newly created user uid but Toast shows nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you authenticate your users with email and password, no data is saved into [Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore), nor in the [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database). If you need to save the database in the database, you need to write code for that. So once your user is authenticated, you can get the data from the [FirebaseUser](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser) object and write it to the database of your choice.

Comment: I know that real-time data are not stored in the Firestore. My question is that new emails are not listed in the authentication -> users section. I watch different videos where the same code structure followed I as do, but in their cases, email are listed in the authentication -> users section.

Comment: Have you set the proper security rules?

Comment: Yes, I set security rules

Comment: One more I want to share with you, I am run the app on a real device.

Comment: You said that onComplete is triggered. Then it definitely should add a new user while authenticating, right?